# __declspec(dllimport) c structure: access violation

Tags: c++, access-violation, declspec

For some time I have been trying to find a solution for the below problem, but with no success:

1. I have a "c" dll, where the following structure is defined:

file: myDll.h

```
#ifdef EXPORTS
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

EXPORT struct my_test 
{
 unsigned char  dum0000001[2144];                                              
 int            test1[32];                                                                                                  
 unsigned char  test2[32];           
} test;
```

In my c++ executable i include the myDll.h file and try to modify test1 and test2:

```
extern "C" 
{
#include "myDll.h"
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 test.test1[0] = 0; 
 test.test2[0] = 0;
}
```

the program passes correctly through:

```
test.test1[0] = 0;
```

but once

```
test.test2[0] = 0;
```

is reached, i get the following exception:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00401028 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x1000c030.
```

I really do not have an idea what's wrong. Perhaps somebody could give me an advice?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: where's your instance of `my_test`?

Comment: Hi, it is imported form the dll

Comment: The 0x1000c030 address is rather a poor match with the structure declaration.  Don't show us a fake one please.  If it is not fake then a mismatch with the actual struct in the DLL is the obvious failure mode.